# saleor payment gateway setup for stripe and razorpay where to insert our secretkey and public key

Tags: saleor

I am trying to setup payment gateway for saleor ecommerce can anyone help me I am new to python I work usually on java. which file needs to be edited to setup existing gateway with my payment keys

Comment: Please provide details of your configuration that is not working so someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Saleor 2.11 for example these settings get set up via the Dashboard -> Configuration -> Plugins